# Sum(IIF( including results with 0 count

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hey All i am using sum iff to return a count based on  multiple criteria.

i am basically running a report on calls recieved per site, however i need sites with 0 calls included in the result set, with the value of 0 or even Null, if they have no calls for that week.

only issue is that my where cluase has only included sites that have had calls in the week

Any ideas.

Code:

```
SELECT 
 d.sitename,
 count(c.Chargeablecalls) AS All_Calls,
 SUM(IIf(c.ChargeableCalls Like "Chargeable",1,0)) AS Chargeable_calls,
 d.sitetype

FROM
    (Callstatus AS s LEFT JOIN statusconversion AS c ON s.description=c.reportheading)             
INNER JOIN sitedetails AS d ON s.zone=d.zone

WHERE s.date_loaded BETWEEN 
(SELECT reportdate FROM reportMonth) AND (SELECT priorweek FROM reportMonth)
GROUP BY d.sitename, d.sitetype;
```

Comment: please include what you've tried for queries

Comment: hey i have updated the post with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `RIGHT JOIN` for `sitedetails` in order to get all the sites even those with no calls.

You may need to do the first half of query separately and then use that query in the main query.

Answer (score 0):

```
create a new query - qryCallStatus:

SELECT DISTINCT zone, description
FROM Callstatus, reportMonth
WHERE
Callstatus.date_loaded BETWEEN reportMonth.reportdate AND reportMonth.priorweek;

Then change your output query to:

SELECT 
 d.sitename,
 count(c.Chargeablecalls) AS All_Calls,
 SUM(IIf(c.ChargeableCalls Like "Chargeable",1,0)) AS Chargeable_calls,
 d.sitetype
FROM
    (sitedetails AS d LEFT JOIN qryCallStatus AS s ON d.zone=s.zone)             
LEFT JOIN statusconversion AS c ON s.description=c.reportheading
GROUP BY d.sitename, d.sitetype;
```